# Output is not what I had expected from the code

Tags: c

Please explain to me why this program is printing `12 12` as output, and not `7 7`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int addmult(int ii, int jj){
    int kk, ll;
    kk = ii + jj;
    ll = ii * jj;
    return(kk,ll);
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 3, j = 4, k, l;
    k = addmult(i,j);
    l = addmult(i,j);
    printf("\n%d\n%d",k,l);
}
```

Comment: `return(kk,ll)` what is this supposed to do? (In C that returns `ll`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not allow the returning of multiple values from the same function. You could create a structure that holds the 2 values inside the function and return that, but a better approach would be to just call the function once each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
k,ll
```

is the comma operator. The C standard says:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
> sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
> operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

So

```
return(kk,ll);
```

is the same as

```
return ll;
```

and the code can be reduced to

```
int addmult(int ii, int jj){
    int ll;
    ll = ii * jj;
    return ll;
}
```

which makes it obvious that it will return 12 for both calls.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already answered above, The C language does not allow returning multiple values from a function (they are limited only to languages like Python).

Below is how you can achieve the purpose you wanted using `struct` in C

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Pair {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Pair addmult(int ii, int jj){
    int kk, ll;
    kk = ii + jj;
    ll = ii * jj;

    struct Pair p = {kk, ll};
    return p;
}

int main(){

    int i = 3, j = 4, k, l;
    struct Pair p = addmult(i, j);
    k = p.x;
    l = p.y;
    printf("\n%d\n%d\n",k,l);

    return 0;
}
```